# Create bar chart with chart.js where space per bar is the same, overall chart size adjusted

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Here are my Javascript options and two screenshots showing examples of charts I've created. The width of the bars is set to 50 pixels. But the overall size of the chart is the same, even though one chart has two bars and the other five. This means the chart with five bars is squeezed tighter than the one with two, even though the actual bars are all 50 pixels. I'm looking for more consistency between these two charts, so that the one with only two bars would be a much "shorter" chart overall, with spacing to match the one with five bars. Is this possible with chart.js?

```
options: {
    aspectRatio: 3,
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            barThickness: 50,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                suggestedMax: maxAxisX
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            maxBarThickness: 50,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 1]

Comment: you could adjust the height of the canvas based on the number of data rows...

Comment: Yeah, I guess I thought of that. I was hoping maybe there was a setting, but maybe no luck with that. So count the number of data rows when building the chart in Javascript, and insert CSS style based on that?

Comment: If I adjust the height only via CSS, it distorts the chart out of proportion. If I adjust the height and width proportionally via CSS, the font sizes are all different between my charts.

Comment: it distorts if you adjust the height before drawing the chart?

Comment: Maybe I did this wrong. How do I adjust the height before drawing the chart?

Comment: save the data in a variable, then use the variable to set height, then pass the data variable to the chart and draw -- e.g. -- `datasets: data,`

Answer (score 1):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `beforeRender`  hook to define the height of the `canvas` parent `div` depending on the number of bars contained in the chart. This function must also consider the space needed on top and below the chart, especially for drawing the xAxis ticks.

```
plugins: [{
  beforeRender: chart => {
    if (!chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight) {
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight = chart.chart.height - (yAxis.bottom - yAxis.top);
    }
    const barThickness = chart.config.data.datasets[0].barThickness;
    const chartAreaHeight = (chart.config.data.labels.length * barThickness * 2);
    document.getElementById("chartWrapper").style.height = (chartAreaHeight + chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight) + 'px';
  }
}],
```

> Please note that instead of defining the option `aspectRatio`, we need to define `maintainAspectRatio: false`.

Please have a look at the code sample below that produces two charts. This solution uses the latest stable version of Chart.js (2.9.3).

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  plugins: [{
    beforeRender : chart => {        
      if (!chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight) {
        var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
        chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight = chart.chart.height - (yAxis.bottom - yAxis.top);
      }
      const barThickness = chart.config.data.datasets[0].barThickness;
      const chartAreaHeight = (chart.config.data.labels.length * barThickness * 2);
      document.getElementById("chartWrapper").style.height = (chartAreaHeight + chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight) + 'px';      
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    datasets: [{
      barThickness: 20,
      data: [100, 90, 80, 70]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {  
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartWrapper">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```